# extjs inheritance and correct reference

Tags: extjs

hey all so I have this class that makes a panel

```
Ext.define('ryan', {

constructor: 
      function(){
           Ext.create('widget.window',{ //stuff})});
```

then I try to instantiate and object

```
    Ext.onReady(function(){
var a = Ext.create('ryan', {
renderTo: Ext.getBody()

});
```

how can I say .show() with the correct reference? a.show(); doesn't work and I tried other ways of referencing it but to no avail.  I don't want to do just .show INSIDE the class which i can make work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign it to a instance variable

```
this.window = Ext.create('widget.window',{ //stuff})});
```

Then you can access it by calling

```
a.window.show();
```